# $\frac{7}{n}$ as a sum of three unit fractions

Tags: number-theory

could $\frac{7}{n}$ be represented as sum of three positive unit fractions given that $n = 2 \mod 7$ ?

I know $\frac{7}{2}$ is not but for all $n>2$ and $n = 2 \mod 7$ it seems that its representable.

Comment: Can I assume that negative fractions are not allowed (something of the form $-\frac1a$ for $a\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$)?

Comment: @YiFan thanks , i will edit.

Comment: How do you write $\frac 7{23}$ in this manner?  The standard Egyptian Fraction algorithm gives $\frac  7{23}=\frac 14 + \frac 1{19} + \frac 1{583} + \frac 1{1019084}$

Comment: $\frac{7}{23}= \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{230}$ @lulu

Comment: @lulu Alternatively we can also take $$\frac7{23}=\frac1{92}+\frac1{23}+\frac14.$$

Comment: How did you get that?  Simple search or have you got an algorithm?  The next one that fails for the standard algorithm is  $\frac 7{107}$.

Comment: @lulu Not sure about the OP, but I just asked Mathematica to find instances of the equality holding. I don't know a general algorithm, unfortunately.

Comment: $\frac{7}{107}= \frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{344}+\frac{1}{736161}$, the greedy algorithm from its name will tend to add more unit fractions. @lulu

Comment: @YiFan  Thanks.  Pretty sure WA just searches.

Comment: @Ahmad  Thanks.  Oh, agreed as to the greedy algorithm. The only good feature it has is that it always works.  Hard to say much about a general search algorithm...

Comment: @YiFan actually i was looking for an algebraic relation like $\frac{7}{7k+3} = \frac{1}{2k+1}+ \frac{1}{2k+1} + \frac{1}{14k^2+13k+3}$ which means that all numbers $n = 3 \mod 7$ are reprenetable as sum of three unit fractions.

Comment: Partial solution: we actually have
$$\frac7{7k+2}=\frac1{k+1}+\frac{2}{(1+k)(2+7k)}+\frac3{(1+k)(2+7k)},$$ so that if $k\equiv\pm1$ mod $3$ then the latter two can be simplified to unit fractions. So we are left with the case where $3\mid k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schinzel observed[1] that, if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, one can express
$$ \frac{4}{at+b} = \frac1{x(t)}+\frac1{y(t)}+\frac1{z(t)}$$
where $x, y$ and $z$ are polynomial functions of $t$ with positive leading coefficients only if $b$ is not a square modulo $a$.

$2=9=3^2$ is a square modulo 7. Nonetheless, in this particular case, if $n$ is odd, we have

\begin{align*}
n=14k-5 \implies \frac7{n} &= \frac{7}{14k-5}\\
&= \frac{14(3k-1)}{2(3k-1)(14k-5)}\\
&= \frac{2(14k-5)+(14k-5)+1}{2(3k-1)(14k-5)}\\
&= \frac{1}{3k-1}\Bigg(1+\frac12+\frac1{2n}\Bigg).
\end{align*}

If $n=2k$ is even, the task of representing $7/n$ reduces to that of representing $7/k$ and then doubling the resulting denominators.

[1] Andrzej Schinzel. Sur quelques propriétés des nombres $3/n$ et $4/n$, ou $n$ est un
nombre impair, Mathesis, **65** (1956), 219--222; MR **18**, 284, quoted and cited in Guy, Richard. Unsolved Problems in Number Theory. Springer, 2nd ed. (1994), $\S$ D11, pp. 159.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, but perhaps it will inspire someone else to give a full solution. We are seeking a general identity of the form
$$\frac{7}{7k+2}=\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c,$$
where $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ depend on $k$. The obvious thing I tried was to take the guess $a=k+1$, which gives
$$\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac{7}{7k+2}-\frac1{k+1}=\frac{5}{(2+7k)(1+k)}.$$
Now, we can write
$$\frac{5}{(2+7k)(1+k)}=\frac{3}{(2+7k)(1+k)}+\frac{2}{(2+7k)(1+k)}.$$
Observe that $(2+7k)$ and $(1+k)$ are always of opposite parity, so the second term can always be simplified to a unit fraction. You can verify that $3\mid(2+7k)(1+k)$ if $3\nmid k$, so the first term is a unit fraction in this case as well. We have therefore reduced the problem to expressing
$\dfrac7{21k+2}$ as a sum of unit fractions.

Unfortunately, trying $a=nk+c$ for any other choices of $n,c$ don't seem to give useful results. For instance we have
$$\frac{7}{21k+2}=\frac1{3k+2}+\frac{12}{(2+3k)(2+21k)},$$
but I don't see an obvious way to decompose the second term into a sum of two unit fractions. The best case scenario is to end up with an expression in the denominator which the numerator is guaranteed to divide (like the case for the second term above where we are guaranteed a unit fraction), but since the denominator is a quadratic polynomial in general this is not possible unless the numerator is a power of $2$. But this is insufficient; writing $12=2^3+2^2$ doesn't give anything useful above, for instance.

Comment: (I'm quite convinced there's a simple solution to this problem that I'm just not seeing. But this is all I have so far.)